# Can we set two buttons in column in footer component of 'native-base' or can we set height of footer of 'native-base'?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, footer, native-base

I am using native-base components.I want to set two or 2 buttons in column view in Footer.can we set height of Footer?.I am new to React Native.This is view

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add two or more button in the footer like

```
  <Container>
    <Footer>
      <Left>
        <Button transparent>
          <Icon name='arrow-back' />
        </Button>
      </Left>

      <Right>
        <Button transparent>
          <Icon name='menu' />
        </Button>
      </Right>
    </Footer>
  </Container>
```